# Pronated vs neutral chest press

Tags: bench-press, chest, machine, grip

The machine I use for upper chest uses free weight instead of a cable stack but my question is regarding the handles, which are similar to the picture below, and resulting hand position.
[image: 1]

Using the upper part of the handle results in a pronated grip that resembles a barbell bench grip, whereas, the part of the handle that drops down provides more of an almost neutral snd narrower grip. I am just wondering what, if anything, changes between using these grips?

Comment: I'm not an expert of biomechanics or a coach. I can just say that, in my case (with previous shoulder injury) the neutral grip is much easier on my shoulder joints. For a similar topic, search the Alex Leonidas  video about the reverse (vs regular) grip bench press

Comment: @Kinka-Byo - yes that is useful actually. One of my shoulders is often liable to experiencing minor pain after a chest workout because its is a bit tighter and less flexible than the other so I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score -3):

The wide grip can be seen to be a very similar motion to incline bench, while the narrow grip is very similar to a truncated chest fly.

Infact this set up truncates the motion of the fly in such a way that we only have the part which builds most muscle, and that is the part involving the maximal stretch.

Comment: “Flys and Bench develop different muscle group” Could you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: Well, as far as i know, incline bemch fovuses the upper chest and fly targets in standard form dies lower chest

Comment: The upper chest and lower chest are not different muscle groups, and it is literally impossible to target one and not the other.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov - Much as there aren't upper and lower abs. Just the rectus abdominus.